# How can I dynamically generate a polygon shape that moves upward in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

Right now, what I have is shown in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p0o5fvdm/

What I want is the polygon to move up smoothly and fill up the portion below it with some more black color that spans a random width which is aligned with the polygon and keeps moving up smoothly like the top part. I tried to use the following code but it does not retain the shape of original polygon and new polygons are being drawn over old ones resulting in flashes.

This is my animation function:

```
function animate(myShape, canvas, context, startTime) {

    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

    myShape.y1 -= 1;
    myShape.y2 -= 1;
    myShape.y3 -= 1;


    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawShape(myShape, context);


    requestAnimFrame(function() {
      animate(myShape, canvas, context, startTime);
    });
}
```

I added the following code to dynamically set the width of bottom edge using following code just above `context.clearRect`.

```
if(myShape.y2 < 400) {
    myShape.y2 = 400;
    myShape.x2 = Math.random()*300;
    myShape.y3 = 400;
}
```

This is the initial value of `myShape`:

```
var myShape = {
    x1: 200,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 120,
    y2: 400,
    x3: 0,
    y3: 400
};
```

My canvas has a height of 400 pixels. That's why I have used it as reference here. Let me know if I need to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a plan to have a polygon with random width that infinitely scrolls up your canvas:**

- Keep an array of random-X, increasing-Y coordinates that form your polygon.
- The first element, `array[0].y` should be less than zero.
- The last element, `array[array.length-1].y` should be greater than the canvas height.
- Animate by reducing each array.y by 1 during each animation loop.
- When array[1].y is reduced below zero, `shift` array[0] off the beginning of the array.
- When the last array.y is animated onto the visual canvas, push a new element into the array having array.y greater than the canvas height.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var a=[
    {x:rx(),y:-Math.random()*100},  // y above canvas
    {x:rx(),y:ry()}                 // y below canvas
];

// redraw
draw(a);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(){
    // update - move all y's upward
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){ a[i].y-=3; }
    // test if a[1] is off top of canvas
    if(a[1].y<0){a.shift();}
    // test if last a[] is on canvas
    if(a.length<2 || a[a.length-1].y<canvas.height){
        a.push({x:rx(),y:ry()});
    }
    // redraw
    draw(a);
    // request another animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
//
function draw(a){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,a[0].y);
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(a[i].x,a[i].y);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(0,a[a.length-1].y);
    ctx.fill();
}
//
function rx(){ return(canvas.width/2+Math.random()*200); }
function ry(){ return(canvas.height*1.25+Math.random()*canvas.height/2); }
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your algorithm almost solved my problem. There is just one issue.  I need to completely fill the left side of canvas with that polygon and to do that, I need to set the x value of last array element to be zero. But then the shifting causes all the values to finally become zero. Setting the final value of x to something random results in polygons that are not convex and may left a white space on their left side.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I feel kind of stupid for not being able to implement it properly myself. :)

Comment: You're welcome. No feeling stupid ... I suspect you would have gotten it eventually. :-)

Comment: I have one doubt. Since the array only has two elements, aren't `a[1]` and `a[a.length-1]` the same?

Comment: I used `console.log(a.length)` but the output was 3, 4, 5 or 6. I don't understand how that happens since you have only initialized the array with two values. Am I missing something?

Comment: I understand it now. The `animate` function keeps adding array values whenever the length of array is less than two and also when last element is above the bottom of canvas. 

Thanks for the answer mark :)